# Организация сети

Tags: сеть, ip, lan

Как правильно организовать сеть? Есть сервера, есть рабочие станции.Я видел где-то примерно такую схему:

[image]

У меня: - 140 рабочих станций где-то + сервера

- Компьютеры разделены где-то по 20 в одном помещении.
- Все свичи из помещений идут в корневой.
- Учетными записями рулит AD - Отдельный сервер для установки ОС, ПО
- Интернет идет через Шлюз (с прокси)
- Сервера сейчас работают через отдельный канал связи

Подскажите чего не хватает, может что-то улучшить.Имеет ли смысл приводить к схеме как на рисунке?

Дополнение:

[image]

У шлюза несколько IP и он занимается пробросом с локальной сети 2 трафика наружу (через NAT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему именно прокси?

Топологию вы выбираете сами. Естественно, что Сервера обычно в одном месте, клиенты - в другом.

Я бы еще разделил на подсети, настроил между отделами VLAN, дал бы доступ к необходимым серверам только тем, кому они нужны. Чтобы доступ был исключительно к себе самому и никто не мог влезть куда-то еще. Много зависит от вашего оборудования.

В зависимости от важности каких-то задач и при наличии денег, стоит подумать об избыточности. Кроме фаерволов, возможно необходимы системы обнаружения вторжений и т.п.

Документацию и схемы всегда стоит вести. Все подписывать. Постоянно идет выбор между полным и необходимым контролем, а также его стоимостью.

Comment: Прокси для экономии трафика. Насчет топологии больше интересует имеет ли смысл использовать 1 гейт вместо двух как на картинке и как тогда организовать доступ к серверам. Возможно ли обеспечить избыточность корневого свича?

Comment: Т.е. благодаря кешированию, вы хотите сэкономить? Хорошая точка зрения. Насчет гейта вопрос не совсем понял. С гейтами все зависит от того, что необходимо и от кого закрыть, если можно от сетевых машин сервера не защищать, то пожалуйста, но если это необходимо, то никуда не деться. Как минимум, необходим гейт на входе. Насчет избыточности корневого свитча могу сказать, что вряд ли. Хотя тоже смотря для каких целей. Если он поддерживает избыточные каналы и их переключение, то можно что-то придумать для внутренней сети. Но думаю, что вам пока не стоит на этом заморачиваться.

Comment: Я бы сказал что за счет кэширования мы экономим) Насчет гейта идея следующая: посадить всю сеть за прокси и NAT. Естественно сервера придется как то пробрасывать наружу можно ли как то сделать несколько IP для одной машины? Ну и один шнур в корневой свич (для интернета рабочим станциям) второй в свич с серверами (чтобы пробрасывать их через NAT, естественно только внешние сервера).

Comment: Проиллюстрируйте пожалуйста вашу идею, не до конца на словах понимаю, для чего вам нужны несколько IP для одной машины.

Comment: Дополнил. Думаю пояснит то что я имел ввиду

Comment: Так если сервера висят на одно и том же шлюзе, не важно в какой сети (судя по вашей схеме), доступ к ним будет всегда, т.е. придумывать ничего не нужно. Что касается NAT, то вы для необходимых серверов настраиваете проброс извне - DNAT. Ничего не меняя во внутренней организации IP-адресов.

Comment: Сейчас внешние напрямую выходят в интернет. Там свич подключен во внешнюю сеть, IP стоят статические.

Comment: Значит ваша схема где-то не дорисована. Потому, что в вашем случае, это не играет никакой роли.